# MySQL character set CLI and Workbench show different results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, character-set

[image]
**Q: Character sets shown by the MySQL CLI command lines and my MySQL workbench show different results. Why is that?**

I've run into MySQL 'chcp' error and cannot view my server status after updating my MySQL workbench, current version is 8.0.27. So after searching up some google have found out it's MySQL Workbench bug dealing with other non-Engligsh languages and I've found out some solutions which were to have System variable Path include System32 and MySQL bin folder which are included well to my system path variable. Other solutions were to change my system language to English, or either check to using UTF-8 in my system locale settings. But the first solution would be very inconvenient for me to use my computer and the second solution made my console applications not able to handle non-English characters. The final solution I've found was to change the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\os_utils.py the internal code

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

from utf-8 to other codepage. But I'm anxious that that would occur other internal bugs so I haven't tried it yet.

**Q: Are there any alternative solution to this "chcp" error? except for downgrading the workbench?**

[image]

Comment: Those two clients get their settings from different places.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, especially when they are utterly unrelated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.